# Why pyenv is not showing system version?

Tags: kubuntu, python, python3

I moved to Kubuntu 20.04 recently.Two days ago I installed pyenv and using pyenv i installed python(3.6.8) then I looked for available python versions from pyenv using this command.

```
samip@samip-Inspiron-3521:~$ pyenv versions
3.6.8
```

But it only showed me this recently installed version but my system has python 3.8.2 installed but anyway i used the 3.6.8 as global version using this command

```
samip@samip-Inspiron-3521:~$ pyenv global 3.6.8
```

But now i cannot switch back to system version.

```
samip@samip-Inspiron-3521:~$ pyenv global system
pyenv: system version not found in PATH
```

I am new to linux and programming please give me step-by-step solution.

```
samip@samip-Inspiron-3521:~$ echo $PATH
/home/samip/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv/shims:/home/samip/.pyenv/shims:/home/samip/.pyenv/bin:/home/samip/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1266731/edit) to clearly describe, step-by-step, how you changed versions. It's important to know that to be able to help you change back.

Comment: @guiverc The release is Kubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 3):

The problem on a fresh Kubuntu 20.04 installation is that there is no python executable. The `/usr/bin` only has `python2` and `python3` but pyenv checks for `python` to determine if a system version is available.

As a workaround create a python executable yourself:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

Answer (score 2):

The prior answers solve this manually; there is also a package that will make the link: `python-is-python3`.  Useful for including in your standard set of packages to install when setting up a new system.

Related GitHub bug thread: [Pyenv can't find system python (3.8) on Ubuntu 20.04 (#1613)](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1613)